# Define orderby in url

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, order

is there a way to set the order of posts via the url?

/orderby/date/order/desc/

i have tried several things with add_rewrite_rule whiteout success.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse13483_init' );
function wpse13483_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( 'category/(.+?)/orderby/([^/]+)/order/([^/]+)(/page/?([0-9]{1,}))?/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[5]&orderby=$matches[2]&order=$matches[3]', 'top' );
}
```

best, Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding this in the functions.php file works. Just **remember to re-save your permalinks** & empty the cache a few times to see the changes.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse13483_init' );
function wpse13483_init() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'category/(.+?)/orderby/([^/]+)?/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&orderby=$matches[2]&order=asc', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'category/(.+?)/orderby/([^/]+)/order/([^/]+)?/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&orderby=$matches[2]&order=$matches[3]', 'top' );
//  with pagination;
    add_rewrite_rule( 'category/(.+?)/orderby/([^/]+)/order/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})?/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&orderby=$matches[2]&order=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]', 'top' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating *URL rewrite* rules is something entirely different from *using URL query variables to sort the Loop query*.

I would suggest  tackling the latter, before worrying about the former.

First, you need to register your URL query variables, e.g. (in `functions.php`):

```
function mytheme_loop_sort_queryvars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'loop_orderby';
    $qvars[] = 'loop_order';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'mytheme_loop_sort_queryvars' );
```

So, now that you've registered your query vars, use them to modify the default Loop query.

First, prepare the query variables, e.g. (in the appropriate *template* files):

```
<?php

// Orderby Query Filter
$loop_orderby = '';
// Array of valid 'orderby' parameters, for validating the URL query string
$valid_loop_orderbys = array( 'ID', 'author', 'title', 'date', 'modified', 'parent', 'rand', 'comment_count', 'menu_order' ); //note: excluding 'meta_value', for simplicity
// Do something only if the query var is set
if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['loop_orderby'] ) ) {
    // Make sure that only a valid 'orderby' parameter is used
    // If URL string value isn't valid, use default 'date'
    $title_filter = ( in_array( $wp_query->query_vars['loop_orderby'], $valid_loop_orderbys ) ? $wp_query->query_vars['loop_orderby'] : 'date' );
}
// Order Query Filter
$loop_order = '';
// Array of valid 'order' paramters, for validating the URL query string
$valid_loop_orders = array( 'ASC', 'DESC' );
// Do something only if the query var is set
if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['loop_order'] ) ) {
    // Make sure that only a valid 'order' parameter is used
    // If URL string value isn't valid, use default 'DESC'
    $title_filter = ( in_array( $wp_query->query_vars['loop_order'], $valid_loop_orders ) ? $wp_query->query_vars['loop_order'] : 'DESC' );
}
?>
```

Now, use the query variables to modify the loop. First, set up your custom argument array:

```
<?php
$custom_orderby_query_args = array();

if ( '' != $filter_loop_orderby ) {
    $custom_orderby_query_args['orderby'] = $filter_loop_orderby;
}
if ( '' != $filter_loop_order ) {
    $custom_orderby_query_args['order'] = $filter_loop_order;
}
?>
```

Now, merge your custom argument array with the default loop query args:

```
<?php
// Globalize the default query
global $wp_query;
// Merge arguments
$customized_query_args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, $custom_orderby_query_args );
// Modify the query output
query_posts( $customized_query_args );
?>
```

Note: you'll have to determine exactly how you're *applying* the URL query strings. This code just uses the query strings once they're in place.

Comment: thanks chip - i have to my embarrassment asked this exact question before. The solution is quick but you have to clear the cache and update your permalinks every time you make a change which was why i wasn't getting anywhere. I've added the answer below. Thanks all the same.